# What is the impact of ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I use Rails in production with Passenger. The app is able to handle multiple requests in parallel

In a migration helper code I establish a connection to an old database to copy data to the new one.

As the connection is made by calling
    `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`, does it affect only the current request or may it have some side effects ?

Just after getting the data I restore the connection to the Rails env.

(My guess is that Passenger spawns multiple processes therefore this should not be a problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a normal pasenger deploy this is not a problem at all. It indeed just spawns multiple processes. They do not share any state, so there cannot be any side effects.

If you would use passenger enterprise in a multithreaded setup this could be some concern. But establish_connection, to my knowledge, takes care of grabing a new connection from the connection pool and saves it into Thread.current hash for this Class. So there should be also no side effects, like having the connection globally switched for other requests.

Take a further look at [Concurrency and Database Connections with ActiveRecord](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections)